DOM Exception while registering the service worker
I am getting this error when I am trying to register the service worker in my project. Its in react 15.1.
DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/az24416/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/az24416/serviceworker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
export default function swDev(){
    let swUrl = `/serviceworker.js`
    console.log(navigator.serviceWorker);
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(swUrl).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    })
}


probably a 404 file not found error and your server is sending HTML instead of the JS your code is expecting

In webpack.config.js, replace the header object to 'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'

I cannot see webpack.config.js in my project. Can you provide a snippet
