Is it possible to add service worker to existing react project, which was not created using create-react-app
I am working on a project that has react version 15.1 and node version 8. The project was not made using create-react-app. Is it possible to add service worker in this project. If yes please provide the guidelines.
Tried registering the service worker but it did not work.

Tried registering the service worker but it did not work. Could you show us what you tried?

Hi @NicholasTower can you see this, I have already posted it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78405956/dom-exception-while-registering-the-service-worker?noredirect=1#comment138227633_78405956
